# E: Unable to locate package in multistage Docker build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I build just the main image, all the packages instead.  But as soon as I turn it into a multi-stage build and it gets to `RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip`, I get "E: Unable to locate package  in multistage Docker build"

```
FROM gcc:8.2.0 as builder
# FROM ownyourbits/debiandev:latest

RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install -y libxerces-c-dev automake cmake libboost-all-dev  build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y libxerces-c-dev automake cmake libboost-all-dev  build-essential
RUN git clone https://github.com/mypackage/mypackage-d.git
WORKDIR /mypackage-d/
RUN autoreconf -if
RUN ./configure --enable-silent-rules 'CFLAGS=-g -O0 -w' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 -w' 'LDFLAGS=-g -O0 -w'
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN ls .

# Main Image
FROM library/python:3.7-stretch

COPY --from=builder /mypackage-d/mypackaged.bin /mypackage-d

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client

RUN apt-get install -y libxerces-c-dev

# For VIM
RUN apt-get install -y apt-file
RUN apt-file update
RUN apt-get install -y vim

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org -r /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /code

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "start.sh"]
```

Comment: did you try to combine the apt-get update and installs in one RUN command (best practice)

Comment: @lvthillo, I did just make that change to try to fix another problem.  The error I reported here went away when I moved the COPY from=builder command below all the main image's apt-get and pip install commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `COPY --from=builder` command below the apt-get install and pip install statements worked for me.